# Can Android Wearable devices detect body temperature?

Tags: android, wear-os, tizen-wearable-sdk

I am looking to plan an application , which can detact the body temperature of the body and take actions accordingly, does android wearablesa best fit for these ?

Comment: If you build your own Android Wear device that offers some sort of skin-contact temperature sensor, perhaps.

Comment: DOes this mean , the devices currently available in the market does nt have the capability to sense our body temperature ?

Comment: The Android SDK does not offer a skin-contact temperature sensor. I am not aware of any existing Android Wear device that offers a skin-contact temperature sensor. Whether one does and it is undocumented, or whether there are non-Android Wear devices that offer a skin-contact temperature sensor, I cannot say. You should consult with a physician to determine if measuring the temperature with a wrist-wearable (or other form factor) device would be accurate. You should also hire an attorney and determine the rules and regulations involved in providing medical advice ("take actions accordingly").

Answer (score 3):

No, there's no Android Wear devices yet with a body temperature monitor.

There's also no Android APIs yet to read this kind of sensor.
Currently the [Google Fit SDK](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/fitness/FitnessScopes.html#SCOPE_BODY_READ) only allows:

- heart_rate_bpm
- height
- weight

It might happen in the future but both software and hardware need to evolve.

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no Android Wear device which detects body temperature.

Basis Peak (not based on Android Wearable) will be the first smartwatch able to monitor skin temperature, but it's not released yet and little information about it is available.